# Über den Ausdruck "etw hinter sich haben"

Tags: meaning

Kürzlich bin ich auf den folgenden Satz gestoßen:

> Sie haben ihre Prüfung hinter sich.

Impliziert dieser Satz, dass die Prüfung erfolgreich abgeschlossen wurde, also dass der Prüfling die Anforderungen erfüllt und die Prüfung bestanden hat, oder weigert sich der Sprecher zu erklären, wie die Prüfung abgeschlossen wurde, und trifft eine neutrale Aussage?

Comment: Man kann *auf etwas stoßen* oder *über etwas stolpern*. Aber *über etwas stoßen* ist falsch. Ich habe deine Frage entsprechend korrigiert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Satz ist neutral, solange der Kontext nicht mehr verrät.

Nicht jede Prüfung kann man wiederholen. Bei Prüfungsangst kann der Fokus ganz auf der Angst liegen, nicht auf dem Erfolg. Eine solche Ansprache ist wohl selten, wenn der Sprecher weiß, dass die Prüfung vermasselt wurde, aber auch nicht ausgeschlossen.

Bei Betonung des *hinter* im *hinter sich*, wenn man die Prüfung beliebig oft versuchen kann, würde ich so deuten, dass ich sie nicht mehr vor mir habe.